# Ruby-on-Rails - Creating a database with relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm completely new to RoR, and I would like to build a simple website that has a bunch of questions, and a bunch of answers associated with each question. The user selects one answer associated with each question, and there are multiple questions. Then, after finishing, the user would then click the submit button, and I would store their data into my database.

What I'm having trouble with figuring out is how should I store the questions and the answers that I will define myself? Based on a little bit of experience with databases, I think I should construct two databases, one for questions, and one for answers associated with each question. How should I do so and how do I do so?

EDIT: I meant two tables, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One db is enough. You should have 2 tables (questions and answers):

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body
  belongs_to :question
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body
  has_many :answers
end
```

This is assuming that each question has many possible answers

The models + migrations can be generated:

```
rails g model Question body:string
rails g model Answer body:string question:references
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to Igor's answer, you'll need to set up 2 models & tables (Questions & Answers) with these columns:

```
#rails generate migration AddQuestionsAndAnswersDatabases
class AddQuestionsAndAnswersDatabases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t| #-> creates questions table
        t.string :body
        t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :answers do |t| #-> creates answers table
        t.integer :question_id
        t.string  :body
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This will create the databases for you, and then you can just run the "`rake db:migrate`" command to migrate them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for furthering Igor's answer. I'm a little bit confused by your answer though, because I think Igor's answer created the models and tables for me already, no?

Comment: Sorry I didnt explain myself properly! Igor demonstrated the _relations_ your mods should have, and I just showed how the corresponding tables would look (I.E the answers table would have to have a question_id column :) hope that helps?

Comment: Can we please move this discussion to a chat? (I'm not sure how to start one) EDIT: nvm here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39153/ror-creating-model-relations

Comment: Hi Rich, I didn't save your e-mail. mind if we work on this again this weekend?

Comment: @RichPeck, migrations are created in the last 2 commands in my answer. Not sure what you meant

Comment: @RichPeck what was your e-mail again? I would like some help.